# Long comments text is hidden by Careers AD or other regular side bar DIV's?

Tags: support, bug, sidebar

[See here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640375/what-is-the-most-complicated-c-variable-type-possible)

[image]

That's a bug of the SE UI layout engine, isn't it?

Comment: ... That moment when I realize on my work machine, I don't see the sidebar ads. On that note, Related does the same thing in this case. By that, I mean Related overlays the comment text.

Comment: @Kendra Well, you might not have that careers option set to active, but as you state that the **Related** DIV is hiding the comments text on your view as well, strongly indicates, that **this is some kind of layout bug**.

Comment: That could be it, but I dunno since I see the ads on my laptop at home. Either way, yeah, looks like some kind of layout bug, probably caused by that first comment.

Comment: @Kendra Yeah, the 1st comment seems to introduce this.

Comment: When I look at the link, I don't see the error - on MacBook Chrome

Comment: The comment was deleted, now we can't see the bug!

Comment: I've never seen this. What browser (inc. version) are you using, and on what operating system?

Comment: @Joe Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m, Windows 7